# How to get effect for "new window" form example

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to get effect for new window/popup when I Click Edit.

[now it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ6iz.png)

I want to the "Edit user" section appears after when i Click Edit but in this way:

[example what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFIaA.png)

here is the code:
link to the JSfiddle in comment
JS

```
'use strict';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        for (var i in data.people) {
            var name = data.people[i].imię && data.people[i].nazwisko;
            var p = '<div id="data"> <p>'+name+'</p></div>';
            $('#name').append(p);
        }
        for (var i in data.people) {
            var mail = data.people[i].mail;
            var p = '<div id="data"> <p>' + mail + '</p></div>';
            $('#mail').append(p);
        }
        for (var i in data.people) {
            var ico = data.people[i].ico;
            var z = '<div class="action">' + ico +'<div id="dropDown" class="menu">' +
                '<a href="#Edit">Edit</a><a href="#Remove">Remove</a></div></div></div>';

            $('#actions').append(z);
        }

        var p ='<div class="dropbtn">';
        $('.action').append(p);


        $('.dropbtn').click(function () {
            $('.menu').removeClass('show');
            $(this).siblings('.menu').addClass('show');
        });

    }
});
```

Somebody could give me a hint pls

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/RobDee/eLkjLfoc/8/

Comment: jquery UI Dialog? https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss that's nice but I need smth easier

Comment: I added a small bit of bootstrap for the table (easier to style) in a sample fiddle with a dialog: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/rvpvwgza/1/ - seems pretty easy, use as you wish.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Looks great but wont work.. $ is not defined in js:22 i added all freamworks and stylesheets

Comment: here is html https://jsfiddle.net/RobDee/axkLLoc0/ maby I dont add all frameworks ?

Comment: Your fiddle does not pull in the external js files, how fiddle works.  Put that in the lower left and it might work - see the 404 errors

Comment: Might also use codepen at http://codepen.io/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss works! but i Have question. How can I made window tittle for "create new" this is the same window like for edit. I search in libries but I can't find it

Comment: got it :) I dont see the form...

Answer (score 0):

```
var editPopup = $('.edit');

$('body').on('click', '.action-edit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

  var index = $(this).closest('.action').index();
  var name = $('#name div').eq(index).text();
  var mail = $('#mail div').eq(index).text();

  editPopup.find('#dataEdit input').val(name);
  editPopup.find('#emailInput').val(mail);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tabkgyem/1/

Comment: thx for answer, hmm it gets data only from last cell. and I need this effect
edit user window to appear in the foreground :(

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on this site. You should provide more information in your answer. What was wrong with the original approach, and what did you change to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you uesed simplemodal plugin?if it is ,the code like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script   type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"  ></script>
<script   type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
<title>example</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #lol
    {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        border:1px red solid;
    }
    #osx-overlay
    {
        background-color:black;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //chrome 49
    $(function()
    {
        $("#lol").modal({
            overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
            overlayClose: true,
            opacity:20,
        });
    })
    //Note the version of simplemodal(1.4.4) and jquery
</script>
</head
<body>
    <div id="lol"></div>
</body>
</html>
```